# Flutter range slider not moving

Tags: flutter, dart

I am showing simple RangeSlider in the bottom sheet issue is it's not moving .

My code

```
  onTap:(){
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context){
          return Column(
            children: [
              
              RangeSlider(
                values: _currentRangeValues,
                min: 0,
                max: 10000,
                divisions: 10,
                labels: RangeLabels(
                  _currentRangeValues.start.round().toString(),
                  _currentRangeValues.end.round().toString(),
                ),
                onChanged: (RangeValues values) {

                },
              ),
            
            ],
          );
        }
    );
  },
```

I am setting the   `RangeValues _currentRangeValues = const RangeValues(0, 10000);` in state.

Its not moving and printing 0 always.

Answer (score 0):

Set the onChanged value to _currentRangeValues to resolve your issue.

```
MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  RangeValues _currentRangeValues = const RangeValues(0, 1000);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RangeSlider(
      values: _currentRangeValues,
      min: 0,
      max: 1000,
      divisions: 10,
      labels: RangeLabels(
        _currentRangeValues.start.round().toString(),
        _currentRangeValues.end.round().toString(),
      ),
      onChanged: (RangeValues values) {
        setState(() {
          _currentRangeValues = values;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```